# Dismiss Ctools popup on click of a button(running on ajax) inside ctools popup

Tags: ajax, chaos-tool-suite

I have created a ctools popup in which I have 2 buttons(add to cart and add to wishlist) which run on ajax.I have used Commerce Ajax Add to Cart module(https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart) which displays the popup showing the details of product added to cart when I click on add to cart.

The thing I want to do is when I click on add to cart button ctools popup should be dismissed and only the popup showing the details of product added to cart should be displayed.I tried

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ 
Drupal.Ctools.Modal.dismiss();
});
```

but using this the popup gets dismissed even if I click on add to wishlist as it also runs on ajax.

Any help would be of great use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Drupal Answers! I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the title, maybe you can make it a little shorter? You don't have to put all information in there :-) Good luck with your site, I hope Drupal Answers will help you out.